# Reverse Osmosis Water machine -- possible kosher issues?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, technology, water

There’s a machine at a local store near me that has a [reverse osmosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_osmosis) water machine. I don't think there is a hecsher on the machine, but it's just water. Is there any possible kosher issues with it, just in general (possible filter issues)?

Comment: Where does the water to be purified come  from? Did it contain any non-kosher stuff?

Comment: What problem could there possibly be with such a device? I’d imagine it would have fewer issues than regular filtered water; the water’s cleaner, and the machine is used with plain water and nothing else.

Comment: @DonielF what if they don't use plain water for the source? I don't know if they do or not, but if there's no hechsher how can you be sure?